# sql statement for some union query - rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, rails-activerecord

Suppose I have a `Message` model with `sender` and `receiver` attributes. What is the rails way to fetch all the messages that where exchanged between two users ? I wrote some scope and

```
scope :some_scope, lambda { |sender = nil, receiver = nil| where({:sender_id => sender, :receiver_id => receiver})}
```

and then I concatenate `Message.some_scope(some_receiver,some_sender)` and `Message.some_scope(some_sender,some_receiver)` but I don't think it is a best practice (btw, I didn't find a simple way to make `union` statement in `rails`)

Answer (score 3):

It is better to use a class method in this case since it is both complex and takes arguments. Also, rather than using a union, you can just `or` the two conditions you care about together.

```
def self.conversation(id1, id2)
  id1_to_id2 = where(sender_id: id1, receiver_id: id2).where_values.reduce(:and)
  id2_to_id1 = where(sender_id: id2, receiver_id: id1).where_values.reduce(:and)
  where(id1_to_id2.or(id2_to_id1))
end
```

Now you can do something like:

```
Message.conversation(user1.id, user2.id)
```

That will give you all messages between `user1` and `user2`.

Comment: ["Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes."](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments) so I think that *probably be cleaner* should be a *you should use a class method*. That's just nit picking though.